# large SVG's not loading completely

Tags: html, svg

I got these svgs from a designer, and they work fine when put inline on an empty page. They also work fine when loaded in as an image. However, for some reason, the 12kb SVG's I have start getting weird when I put them inline on a wordpress page.

Here is a link to the site in question: http://162.214.14.26/~naturesfusions/

As you can see, parts of the icons are getting cut off, and on one of them the icon seems to be ignoring paths set in the svg. The weird thing is this seems to only effect large-ish svg's and not the simple 3kb ones I have. Any ideas on what's wrong here?

Comment: The icon is being cropped due to the `<mask id='mask-2'>` element. If you remove it then it appears fine

Comment: yes, this solved it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

id attributes must be unique within a document. You have multiple elements with the same id e.g. id="Home" so your document is invalid. Weird things happen with invalid documents.

Comment: So if all of the elements have unique ids, it should fix it?

Comment: Thanks, turns out it was an issue with a mask in another svg that was making them all act weird. But this should prevent issues like this from happening again.